# Usar o addslashes contra injeção de SQL é seguro?

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados, segurança

Usar o `addslashes()` realmente é seguro contra injeção de SQL? Se não, me diga o motivo.

Vou usar assim o meu `addslashes()`

```
<?php
$id = addslashes ( $_GET ["id"] ) ; /* Adicionei as barras */
echo stripslashes ( ( "$id" ) ) ; /* Removi as barras para exibir só as aspas no echo  */
?>
```

O modo que eu vou usar está correto ou vai deixar vulnerável o sistema?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Há chances de deixar o sistema vulnerável.

Esse [**artigo**](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string), *addslashes() Versus mysql_real_escape_string()* cita um bom motivo para isso.

Em tradução livre:

> Se eu quero tentar um ataque de injeção SQL contra um banco de dados
> MySQL, tendo escapado aspas simples com uma barra invertida é uma
> chatice.
>
> Se você estiver usando addslashes(), no entanto, estou com sorte.
> Tudo o que preciso fazer é injetar algo como `0xbf27` e addslashes()
> retornará `0xbf5c27`, um caractere multi-byte válido seguido por um apóstrofo.
>
> Em outras palavras, eu posso injetar com sucesso uma apóstrofo,
> apesar de escapado. Isso porque `0xbf5c` é interpretado como um
> caractere único, não dois. Ops, lá se vai a barra invertida.

Relacionado: [**Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/como-prevenir-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-c%C3%B3digo-sql-no-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php)

Como citado na pergunta acima, prefira utilizar [`PDO`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) ou funções [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php).

Esse [**outro artigo**](http://www.itshacked.com/344/bypassing-php-security-addslashes-while-sql-injection-attacks-is-possible.html) explica como injetar um código SQL ao usar a função [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php).

A função [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php) é amplamente usada para retornar uma *string* com barras invertidas antes de caracteres que precisam ser citados no banco de dados. Esses caracteres são aspas simples `'`, aspas duplas `"`, barra invertida `\` e *Null* (o [Caractere nulo](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caractere_nulo)).

- O apostrofo `'` retorna `\'`.
- `' OR '1' = '1` vai retornar `\' OR \'1\' = \'1`.

Em um [conjunto de caracteres de byte único](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374056%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a seqüência `\'` é visto pelo MySQL como `0x5c` e `0x27`. Isto é `\` → 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 e `'` → 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1.

Num conjunto de [caracteres de vários bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/4bb3e64h.aspx) como [Big5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5) um *byte* é usado para *ascii* e dois bytes são utilizadas para caracteres *Big5*. As vezes, há uma reviravolta quando um banco de dados MySQL, tabela ou coluna usa um conjunto de caracteres de vários bytes. Se um caractere *Big5* tem como último byte o `0x5c` (*valor para barra invertida*), podemos enganar a função [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php) a formar o caráter de dois bytes *Big5* quando se insere a barra invertida.

- `¿` → 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
- `'` → 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1

Quando essa seqüência é passada através da função [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php), uma barra invertida é inserida: *0xBF* → `¿` **0x5c** → `\` *0x27* → `'`.

- `¿` → 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
- `\` → **0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0**
- `'` → 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1

O MySQL com o conjunto de caracteres *Big5* interpreta essa *string* como sendo `0xbf5c` (`0xBF` seguido por `0x5c`) e `0x27`( `'`).

- `縗` → **1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0**
- `'`  → 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1

Note que o apóstrofo não foi escapado quando processado pelo MySQL, e agora vai agir como um delimitador que permitirá injetar um código SQL.

Isso funciona por duas razões:

1. O valor `0xbf5c` é um caractere de dois bytes válido em [Big5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5).
2. A função [`addslashes`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addslashes.php) não verifica o conjunto de caracteres no MySQL.

Por isso, alguns [conjuntos de caracteres de vários bytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/4bb3e64h.aspx) permite um ataque direcionado em `addslashes` que resulta em injeção de SQL bem sucedido.

Qualquer caractere de vários bytes definido com valor de `0x5c` no último *byte* de um caractere válido estava vulnerável. Conjuntos vulneráveis incluído [Big5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big5), [GBK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK), e [SJIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SJIS) entre outros. Este problema foi corrigido no [MySQL em 2006](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=22243). Mas pessoas mal-intencionadas podem explorar maneiras de atacar usando esses conjuntos de caracteres.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: Eu posso usar esse metodo assim então? $tarefa =      mysql_real_escape_string ( $_GET [ "tarefa" ] ) ;

Comment: @LucasC.S Sem problema, mas use `mysqli_real_escape_string` por via das dúvidas.

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: Vou começar a usar PDO, mas não quero largar o velho mysql

Comment: é interessante usar o var_dump($tarefa); pra ver a função

Answer (score 3):

Isto não é seguro. Especialmente se não estiver usando MySQL. Outros banco de dados não usam a mesma sintaxe e não se beneficiam disto. A própria [documentação da função](http://php.net/addslashes) indica que funções específicas para cada banco de dados devem ser usadas para prevenir injeções.

Provavelmente você está usando o MySQL. Neste caso pode até ajudar, mas ajudar não é suficiente. [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) deve ser usada no lugar, dependendo da forma como está se comunicando com o MySQL. Ela é especifica para este banco de dados e entende melhor o que pode permitir uma injeção de código e sabe evitar a injeção de um jeito adequado. Existem outras formas possíveis.

Existe uma [página bem conhecida](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string) que mostra uma forma de ataque injetando SQL fazendo fazendo escape com barra.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score -1):

Crie sempre uma função de anti_injection, é o que tenho utilizado sempre para segurança em sistemas de logins

```
// Função de Eliminação de qalquer comando que possa invadir ou alterar o sistema de forma indevida
function anti_injection($sql){
    $sql = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"), "" ,$sql); // remove palavras que contenham sintaxe sql
    $sql = trim($sql); // limpa espaços vazios
    $sql = strip_tags($sql); // tira tags html e php
    $sql = addslashes($sql); //  adiciona barras invertidas a um string
    return $sql;
}
```

É isso que tenho usado, apenas estou em um dilema com as senhas em MD5, quando coloco a senha em MD5 eu não utilizo o anti_injection, pois o MD5 já "protege", e se usar o anti_injection a senha não pode conter * (asteriscos) e no meu caso utilizo muito * nas senhas

Comment: Não era mais fácil usar algum sistema de parametrização pras queries?

Comment: @LINQ pior que não usar a ferramenta nativa é detonar strings válidas na tentativa de sanitizar.

Comment: @Bacco Nem tinha atentado a isso, e nem que a resposta já tem 2 anos hehehe

Answer (score -1):

Pode usar também o preg_replace() desta forma:

```
$text = "090933ojeoejf'@#$%";

/* Para deixar apenas letras */
$text = preg_replace("/[^[:alpha:]_]/", "", $text);

/* Para deixar letras e números */
$text = preg_replace("/[^[:alnum:]_]/", "", $text);
```

se quiser pesquisa mais sobre esta função.

Comment: Mas e se for permitido haver símbolos? E como esse código é mais seguro que a função `addslashes`?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss certamente este codigo é mais seguro, que `addslashes`, porque a probabilidade de `SQli` é minima ja que utiliza simbolos, na parte dos símbolos(acentuação, retirando operadores), é desnecessário e não vejo utilidade nenhuma passar símbolos(retirando operadores) via `$_GET` como o autor citou

Comment: Voce adicionar mais caracteres para validar (permitir), e como foi dito e exemplificado la em cima, a addslashes() tem prechas como o caractere binario mencionado. fiz uns testes aqui mais não no banco fiz para remover de dados passados na URL, e funciona muito bem.