# Qual a melhor opção para escapar uma string antes de inserir na base de dados. addslashes() ou mysql_real_scape_string()?

Tags: php, sql

Estou a desenvolver um projeto que envolve palavras pass entre outras infomações importante que preciso de inserir na base de dados mysql.

A minha dúvida é qual a opção que devo usar para escapar esses dados contra sql injection. Neste momento estou a usar uma expressão regular que retira os caractéres indesejados. Estou a usar o PDO.

Comment: Para inserir dados no banco de dados, usa o `mysql_real_escape_string`, depois se possível explico melhor o porquê. Aproveita e lê isto - [Porquê não usar funções mysql_*](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/por-que-n%C3%A3o-devemos-usar-fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es-do-tipo-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_real_scape_string()` deve ser descartada por ser obsoleta, removida do php7 e por necessitar de uma conexão mysql_*.

Deixe que o PDO se encarregue de escapar os caracteres utilizando prepared statements.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Usar o addslashes contra injeção de SQL é seguro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50839/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

[Usar PDO é a maneira mais segura de se conectar a um BD com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)

Comment: Eu estive a ler um pouco sobre o addslashes e fiquei na dúvida porque havia um artigo que explicava que esse método não era seguro. Daí a minha dúvida.

Comment: Usar o addslashes é quase a mesma coisa que forçar a utilização do `quotes` no `PDO`, é mais ou menos esta a ideia.