# mysqli_real_escape_string Previne SQL Injection?

Tags: php, sql, segurança, sql-injection

Segundo a documentação, a função: Escapa caracteres especiais em uma seqüência de caracteres para uso em uma instrução **SQL**, levando em consideração o conjunto de caracteres atual da conexão.

Então:

- Existe uma possibilidade de **SQL Injection** mesmo quando se utiliza a função `mysqli_real_escape_string()`?
- Se usada em conjunto com um `filter_input` ao receber dados, poderia melhorar o nível de segurança da aplicação?
- Quais funções poderiam ser combinadas para que a aplicação fique mais segura neste cenário de Prevenção a **SQL Injection**?

> Referências:
>
> [Mysqli Real Escape String](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)
>
> [Filter Input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php)

Comment: você pretende utilizar em formulário, login, ou o que ?

Comment: Acredito que qualquer página que faça uma consulta pode ser incluída no cenário, desde um `$_GET` com id de uma página até um formulário com iteração com o banco.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Usar o addslashes contra injeção de SQL é seguro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50839/91) e [Qual a melhor opção para escapar uma string antes de inserir na base de dados. addslashes ou mysql_real_scape_string?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/97601/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Existe uma possibilidade de SQL Injection mesmo quando se utiliza a função mysqli_real_escape_string()?

Tipicamente não, exceto se utilizar *charset estranhos*. Supondo que utilize UTF8MB4 e sempre utilize o `"` (ou `'`) na query, isso será suficiente. O ideal é que *charset* utilizado também, usando o `mysqli_set_charset`.

Inclusive, a [Cure53](https://cure53.de/), uma empresa de segurança, afirma que usar `addslashes` é seguro, desde que sempre utilize um charset seguro (e que por padrão será usado), e sempre inclua o valor sobre `" ... "` na query.

A razão pelo qual isso não é recomendado é simples: você pode esquecer de tratar uma variável com o `mysqli_real_escape_string()` ou esquecer um simples `"`. Claro, apenas um erro poderá levar tudo abaixo.

> Se usada em conjunto com um filter_input ao receber dados, poderia melhorar o nível de segurança da aplicação?

Não. Isso pode até ser pior, afinal você pode criar um novo [Wordpress e suas inúmeras vulnerabilidades de  XSS](https://klikki.fi/adv/wordpress2.html), simplesmente por está "escapando" dados e trucando elas no banco de dados.

Aplicar outros filtros ou limpezas **antes** do `mysqli_real_escape_string` não deixará vulnerável a MySQL Injection, mas *pode criar outros problemas*.

> Quais funções poderiam ser combinadas para que a aplicação fique mais segura neste cenário de Prevenção a SQL Injection?

Nenhuma. Apenas use funções que foram feita para o objetivo desejado. Usar `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`, por exemplo, poderá criar mais problemas e não irá resolver o SQL Injection. O motivo é simples, esse filtro não foi feito para SQL Injection.

Use o `mysqli_real_escape_string` ou use Prepared Statement, essas são as únicas "funções" que devem ser utilizadas para esse fim.

Answer (score 2):

Claro que resolve amigo, faça o teste, crie uma tabela com um campo de login e senha, e faça a seguinte teste (OBS: estou postando o exemplo que eu fiz, eu utilizo uma classe para conexão ao banco mas o processo é o mesmo sem a classe o que interessa é o `SQL`):

```
<?php

include_once 'Query.class.php';

$login = "guilherme";
$senha = "1234";

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE login = "' . $login . '" AND senha = "' . $senha . '"';

echo "<pre>";
print_r(Query::Select($sql));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Esse código me retornou um `Array()` com os dados desse usuário no banco:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [email] => guilherme
            [senha] => 1234
        )

)
```

Então significa que o SQL está buscando as informações no banco corretamente. Teoricamente como retornou algo do banco o sistema só pegaria essas informações e automaticamente logaria o cara ex:

```
<?php

... codigo imaginario anterior ...

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE login = "' . $login . '" AND senha = "' . $senha . '"';
$dados = Query::Select($sql);

if($dados != ""){
    $SESSION["logado"] = $dados[0]; // Como só poderia retornar 1 conjunto de dados eu pego sempre o primeiro (não tem como existir 2 usuários iguais com senhas iguais)
}else{
    // não achou nenhum user que combina com a senha
}

?>
```

O que acontece se não tratar-mos os dados enviados para login? veja o exemplo:

```
<?php

include_once 'Query.class.php';

// SQL Injection
$login = '" or "1';
$senha = '" or "1';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE email = "' . $login . '" AND senha = "' . $senha . '"';

echo "<pre>";
print_r(Query::Select($sql));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

O retorno disso será o seguinte `Array()`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [login] => administrator
            [senha] => admin
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [login] => guilherme
            [senha] => 1234
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [login] => carlos
            [senha] => carlos
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [login] => luiz
            [senha] => luiz
        )

)
```

Veja que ele retornou todos os usuários do banco, e como o primeiro usuário normalmente é o administrador do sistema na hora que esse `Array()` passar pelo script de login a pessoa que colocou o `SQL Injection` será logado como administrador (ou com o primeiro usuário da sua tabela depende de como o programador fez a regra de login dele).

Agora se colocarmos essa querida função `mysqli_real_escape_string()` veja o resultado:

```
<?php

include_once 'Query.class.php';

$login = '" or "1';
$senha = '" or "1';


/*
 * A função Query::AntiSqlInjection() nada mais é que isso:
 * 
 * static public function AntiSqlInjection($str) {
 *      self::AbreConexao();
 *      $str = mysqli_real_escape_string(self::$conn, $str);
 *      self::FechaConexao();
 *      return $sql;
 * }
 * 
 */
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `usuarios` WHERE login = "' . Query::AntiSqlInjection($login) . '" AND senha = "' . Query::AntiSqlInjection($senha) . '"';

echo "<pre>";
print_r(Query::Select($sql));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Desse modo o retorno será `VAZIO`, então a pessoa que tentar colocar qualquer `SQL Injection` nos campos de login e senha serão automaticamente escapados e não reconhecidos (contanto que você não esteja armazenando `SCAPED STRINGS` no banco ex: [ campo login = sergio/marques ou o campo senha = edu'02"/3 ] para evitar esse tipo de dor de cabeça sempre use o `md5` ou `sha1` para criptografar dados/senhas salvas no banco que necessitem de caracteres de scape, assim você deixa seu sistema mais seguro e evita problemas com comparação de dados. Isso não se aplica caso necessite descriptografar algum dado, nesse caso utilize alguma função que disponibilize o modo de criptografia e descriptografia, na internet você encontra várias funções interessantes).