# Adicionar nivel de acesso a esse codigo php

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?PHP
include('config.php');
# Validar os dados do usuário

function anti_sql_injection($string)
    {
        include('config.php');
        $string = stripslashes($string);
        $string = strip_tags($string);
        $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$string);
        return $string;
    }

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from sec_iden where login_sec='".anti_sql_injection($_POST['login_sec'])."' and senha_sec='".anti_sql_injection($_POST['senha_sec'])."' limit 1") or die("Erro");
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($linhas == '')
    {
        ?>
        <div class="msg2 padding20">Usuário não encontrado ou usuário e senha inválidos.</div>
        <?PHP
    }
else
    {
        while($dados=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login_sec_sessao'] = $dados['login_sec'];
                header("Location: conteudo.php");
            }
    }
?>
```

bom eu queria que quando o campo que eu criei na db chamado ( adm fosse = 1 ) ele redirecionasse para administrativo.php
e quando fosse = 0 para conteudo.php
mas não tou conseguindo fazer isso, um if resolveria isso e onde eu colocaria esse if ?

Comment: Alguns dos links: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50839/70 , https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864/70 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256111/70

Comment: Eu já comentei nuns 3 ou 4 posts aqui do site sobre esse "anti injection". Fica a sugestão, arranque a função do código, pq tem uns fóruns que compartilham funções desse tipo, mas só serve pra pessoa passar vergonha. Pesquise aqui mesmo no site como evitar injeção SQL que tem as soluções corretas.

Comment: @Bacco eu já retirei bro, vlw .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, nesse caso um `if` bastaria.

Ficaria assim:

```
<?PHP
include('config.php');
# Validar os dados do usuário

function anti_sql_injection($string)
    {
        include('config.php');
        $string = stripslashes($string);
        $string = strip_tags($string);
        $string = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$string);
        return $string;
    }

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao,"select * from sec_iden where login_sec='".anti_sql_injection($_POST['login_sec'])."' and senha_sec='".anti_sql_injection($_POST['senha_sec'])."' limit 1") or die("Erro");
$linhas = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
if($linhas == '')
    {
        ?>
        <div class="msg2 padding20">Usuário não encontrado ou usuário e senha inválidos.</div>
        <?PHP
    }
else
    {
        while($dados=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
            {
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['login_sec_sessao'] = $dados['login_sec'];
                if($dados['adm'] == '1') header("Location: administrativo.php"); 
                else header("Location: conteudo.php");
            }
    }
?>
```

Note que esse exemplo é válido apenas em caso de duas situações de login como você passou, ou seja, se ele for administrador ou não.

**OBS:** Dessa forma você não está fazendo controle de acesso, estás apenas a redirecionar o usuário para determinada página.

Comment: mt obrigado @jorge Matheus, teria outro jeito que vc aconselharia a está fazendo isso? Eu estava com dúvida onde colocar esse if, vlw pela ajuda !

Comment: No caso de ter mais níveis de acesso, você iria fazendo os `if` de acordo com a permissão, exemplo: `if($dados['editor'] == '1') echo 'permissões para editor' ;`.  Nesse caso você está apenas redirecionando o usuário para a página. E se o usuário que não for administrador jogar no browser `administrativo.php` ? Espero que esteja fazendo os tratamentos nas páginas também. :D

Comment: verdd eu vou fazer esses tratamentos, vlw mano.

Comment: Disponha! Se tiver mais dúvidas pode perguntar. Se for preciso abrimos um chat para debate.

Comment: opa vlw, como eu posso abrir um chat ctg? Eu estou com mais um probleminha eu consegui fazer um tratamento, mas mesmo o usuario tendo permissão 1 ele entra no tratamento e volta para index.php

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83631/discussion-between-jorge-matheus-and-gabriel-costa).