# Podemos evitar SQLInjection apenas com mysqli_real_scape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, segurança

Exemplo:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "user", "password", "my_db");

$pegaNome = $_POST['nome'];


function insere($conexao, $pegaNome) {
     $nome = mysqli_real_scape_string($conexao, $nome);
     $query = "INSERT INTO my_db (nome) VALUES ('{$nome}')";
     $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);
     return $result
}
```

Apenas com esta função eu já impeço qualquer tentativa do usuário final fazer SQLInjection? Quais são as melhores maneiras de se evitar?

Grato!

Comment: Escapar caracteres não resolve o problema de sql injection, [prepared statements](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3869/91) diminuem o risco. Veja [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50841/91)