# addslashes é o basico para a segurança?

Tags: php

Tenho um site com sistema de login, onde encontra-se um fórum com comentários.

Queria saber se a função addslashes seria pelo menos o básico para me prevenir de códigos maliciosos, como redirecionamento de página, sql injection?

Comment: Só depende do contexto. Se é pra prevenir injection, cada api/lib de DB tem sua maneira. Normalmente o addslashes não deve ser usado, e não é essa a finalidade dele.

Comment: PS: Caso as respostas da pergunta indicada como alternativa não sejam suficientes, basta [edit] a sua acrescentando o contexto para deixar mais específica e deixar um comment, que a gente vota pra reabrir.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A função [addslashes()](http://php.net/addslashes) é usada para escapar barras invertidas, aspas simples, dentre outros caracteres. Não é o suficiente para escapar conteúdo HTML, CSS ou JavaScript.

Para escapar conteúdo HTML, use funções como [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags), a qual remove tags ou, use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/htmlentities) caso queira exibir o conteúdo de código HTML como texto.

Exemplo prático sobre as 3 funções:

## addslashes()

```
$str = "Is your name O'Reilly?";

// Outputs: Is your name O\'Reilly?
echo addslashes($str);
```

A função adiciona o caracter de escape <sup>(barra invertida)</sup> para cada single quote <sup>(aspa simples)</sup> encontrada.

Note que no PHP existe a diretiva [magic_quotes_gpc](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc). Em versões inferiores ao PHP5.4, essa diretiva poderia estar ativada. Então é importante verificar se está ativada ou não nessas versões do PHP. Quando `magic_quotes_gpc` está ativo, addslashes() é aplicado automaticamente nas variáveis globais `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_COOKIES`.

## strip_tags()

```
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
```

A função remove tudo que é HTML, e tags JavaScript e CSS.

O segundo parâmetro da função serve para especificar exceções:

```
$text = 'foo<br>bar';
echo strip_tags($text, '<br>');
```

Nesse segundo exemplo, remove todas as tags HTML, exceto a tag `<br>`

Para prevenir-se de ataques de injeções SQL, prefira funções como [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php;net/mysqli_real_escape_string). Para mais detalhes sobre o assunto consulte esse link: [Usar o addslashes contra injeção de SQL é seguro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50839/usar-o-addslashes-contra-inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-sql-%C3%A9-seguro)

## htmlentities

Converte caracteres especiais, ou seja, caracteres não alfa numéricos, em HTML entities.

Falando de forma mais simples, você já deve ter visto códigos desse tipo `a&ccedil&atilde;` no código HTML e na página do browser aparece como `ação`. Isso são os HTML entities.

A principal utilidade é permitir visualizar códigos HTML sem que os mesmos sejam interpretados, ou seja, serão tratados como texto plano (plain/text).

Suponha que deseja exibir um código HTML `<b>texto</b>`. Então poderá usar HTML entities:

```
echo htmlentities('<b>texto</b>');
```

Outro uso comum e não recomendo é para exibir caracteres de idiomas multibyte ou mesmo caracteres latinos com acentuação.

Nota: Não confunda **HTML Entities** com **URL encoded** ([urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode)). Pois ambos são codificações distintas.

Answer (score 1):

Em parte sim, o `addslashes` protege contra a maioria dos códigos de `SQLInjection` mas não todos, sua única funcionalidade é transformar a aspa em caractere acrescentando um arrab (\).

Fora esses comando de `SQLInjection`, existem outros mais complexos que não são feitos através de formulários em sua página, coisa que para uma boa segurança é recomendado o uso de usuários e permissões no banco de dados.

Como é um fórum onde as pessoas podem deixar comentários, é possível fazer a injeção de `javascript`, com scripts de roubo de sessão, exclusão de comentários, entre outros. Caso tenha mais duvidas pesquise por "[**Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)".

Essas são algumas das vulnerabilidades mais comuns que se encontra, ainda existem outros meios de injeção de scripts e invasão de sites. Esse link contem algumas vulnerabilidades conhecidas [**Veja aqui!**](http://wtr2015.pop-pr.rnp.br/static/media/uploads/downloads/vulnerabilidadesweb.pdf)