# como fazer teste com sql injection

Tags: php, sql-injection

Quero fazer uns testes de sql injection. Para isso, criei um db chamado pessoa e uma tabela chamada usuarios. Estou passando algumas instruções sql para testar a ingessão de sql. Dá erro, mas não execulta a query:

arquivo de conexão com o banco:

conexao.php

```
$server="localhost";  
$user="root";  
$password="";  
$database="pessoa";  

//conexao com servidor de banco  
$connect = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password) or print(mysql_error());  

//se a conexao falhar  
if (!$connect) {  
echo "Conexão com servidor errou";    
}  

else {  
    //usar database  
$selectDB = mysql_select_db($database, $connect);     

//se database falhar  
    if (!$selectDB) {  
echo "Conexão com o banco errou";     
    }  
}
```

arquivo index.html

```
<html>  
<body>  

<form name="buscar" id="buscarId" action="server.php" method="post">  

<label for="Nome">Nome</label>  
<input type="text" name="nome" id="nomeId">  

<input type="submit" value="Buscar">  
</form>  >
</body>  
</html>
```

arquivo server.php

```
<?php  

include('connect.php');  

buscar();  

function buscar() {  
   echo "<p>";  
   $select = "select * from usuarios where nome='$_POST[nome]'";      
   $query = mysql_query($select);  
   $rows=mysql_num_rows($query);  

   if ($rows==0) {  
      echo "Nome não encontrado";  
   } else {   
      while ($dados=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {  
         print_r($dados);  
      }  
   }  
}  
?>
```

No formulário que busca pelo nome, ao invés de informar o nome, eu coloco uma query:

select * from users

é claro que isso não é um comando para o banco, é uma busca porque está em aspas simples ou dupla:

`select * from usuarios`

dá o erro:

> ( ! ) Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in \caminho\pasta.

Eu já fiz:

```
$select = "select * from usuarios where nome='.$_POST[nome].'";
```

debugando fica:

```
select * from usuarios where nome='.select * from usuarios.', ou seja, não executa o que está em $_POST;
```

E também fiz:

```
$select = 'select * from usuarios where nome=$_POST[nome]';  

Também não funciona. Só não entendi porque tem que concatenar.
```

Comment: Link obrigatório: http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 2):

Quando você diz:

```
"select * from usuarios where nome='$_POST[nome]'"
```

Você está mandando o seguinte comando para o banco de dados:

```
select * from usuarios where nome='$_POST[nome]'
```

Se você quer concatenar o conteúdo de uma variável na string, faça ao invés disso assim:

```
"select * from usuarios where nome='" . $_POST[nome] . "'"
```

<strike>(ou como quer que vocês programadores PHP façam suas concatenações ;) )</strike> (Valeu pessoal por me mostrar que concatenação em PHP é com ponto!)

Assim o motor do PHP não considerará o trecho `$_POST[nome]` como uma string literal.

Boa sorte!

Comment: Sinal de + (mais) ?

Comment: @Zoom eu nunca programei em PHP na vida e nem li o manual... Tudo que eu conheço de PHP é só olhando por cima do ombro dos meus colegas XD

Comment: Troca o `+` por `.`, com aspas duplas variáveis são interpretadas no php :)

Answer (score 0):

> mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Acontece devido a um erro na consulta, geralmente de sintaxe, para bular seu código, primeiro feche o  select, adicione o terminador e envie uma nova instrução(drop/trucate/delete etc).

O conteúdo de `$_POST['nome']` deve ser `'; delete from usuarios;`

Exemplo, com um driver atualizado(PDO) porém usando tecnicas inadequadas, o valor de `$_GET['id']` é nesse exemplo `; drop table livros`. Veja o resultado as informações do livro são exibidas na tela mas a tabela já não existe mais.

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teste', 'usuario', 'senha');
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM livros WHERE id = '.$_GET['id'] ;
$stmt = $db->query($sql) or die(print_r($db->errorInfo()));
print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

**Relacionado:**

[Usar o addslashes contra injeção de SQL é seguro?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50839/91)

[Como prevenir injeção de código SQL no meu código PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3864/91)

Comment: dê um exemplo de como ficaria o comando. Pelo qu entendi, seria no campo do formulário: "select * from usuarios"; trup table usuarios; seria isso?

Comment: @AndréNascimento, isso ou vc pode fazer algo como ` or true;` o select gerado é algo como: `select * from usuarios where id = 10 or true`

Comment: @AndréNascimento, alguns bancos permite q várias querys seja executadas, separadas por `;` o `mysql_query()` executa apenas uma e ignorar o resto, teste o `OR 1=1` ou `OR true` em operação de delete.

Comment: entendi. Como estou fazendo com uma string que é o nome, fica mais difícil. Fiz com id e funcionou.