# Meu código não da erro, mas também não compila. Não acontece nada :/

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Não sei o que acontece no código. Ele não da erro, mas também não faz o insert e não vai para a tela de Login e também não entra no else de "erro"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não use imagens para mostrar seu código, outras pessoas podem precisar fazer testes e ninguém quer ficar digitando tudo o que você já escreveu. Aconselho você a editar a pergunta e inserir o código nela.

Comment: Seu código tem problemas de lógica, injeção de SQL, e uma race condition no insert, além de estar estruturado de maneira muito mais complexa do que o necessário. Fora isso, como já mencionado, tem uso inadequado de addslashes. Seria legal dar uma estudada melhor e refazer do zero, aprendendo com outras postagens do site. Consertar esse daria mais trabalho do que refazer, então compensa recomeçar certo com mais conhecimento teórico (pra dar menos manutenção depois, inclusive). Pesquise no site sobre injeção de SQL, evitar inserção mais de uma vez, senha segura e também sobre addslashes.

Answer (score 1):

***Como fazer a diagnose?***

Para fazer essa diagnose do que acontece, tens que analisar o que está sendo passado através da solicitação POST e ver se tudo está sendo fornecido a sua aplicação PHP, verificar a grafia correta das variáveis bate (maiúscula, minúscula, algum erro, etc.) No seu caso, deve ser isso...

***Por quê não exibe o erro?***

Ele não exibe o erro que está dentro do else pois ele valida (e entra) no primeiro

`if(isset($_POST['agencia']) && empty($_POST['agencia']) == false)`

e segue para as validações internas que não possuem else, falhando em alguma dessas duas (conta ou senha)...

***Corrigindo o erro***

Adiciona mais alguns elses ali para debugar a sua aplicação de maneira mais fácil, informando ao usuário cada erro, no caso do segundo if coloca um else e ecoa: "Você deve informar o número da conta", na próxima validação, ecoa: "você deve informar a senha", e assim por diante... Se um if passa, e ocorre um erro internamente, ele não vai para o else do anterior.

***Dica extra***

Seu código está suscetível a ataques de injeção de SQL... Você tem que preparar as variáveis de entrada antes com $sql->mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['agencia']). A função addslashes não é recomendada para isso conforme [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50841/54101).

Comment: As dicas são boas, só um detalhe: infelizmente ele está usando PDO, em vez da mysqli, então a "dica extra" não se aplica. De qq forma, está dado o +1